# How do I download the source for BIRT?

Tags: eclipse, cvs, birt

The Eclipse projects are all stored in the Eclipse Foundation CVS servers.  Using the source is a great way to debug your code and to figure out how to do new things.

Unfortunately in a large software project like BIRT, it can be difficult to know which projects and versions are required for a particular build. So what is the best way to get the source for a particular build?

Comment: Yeah, and it gets even more difficult for projects like Eclipse, built out of hundreds of small components. It's a pain to track them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I know the answer to this one...

Eclipse has a feature named Team Project Sets which allows you to define a collection of projects, stored in various version control systems that can be downloaded as a package.  I have published a collection of team project set files that can be used to get the BIRT source.  The files are stored in a Subversion repository [here](http://longlake.minnovent.com/repos/birt_example)

I have a short article with a bit more detail on the [BirtWorld](http://birtworld.blogspot.com) blog.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the BIRT website and follow their [Directions](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/build/buildInstructions.php#checkout).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I want to clarify a couple of things:
Your link points to the BIRT 2.1.1 instructions. 
In that page is a link to a wiki page whic is for BIRT 2.2.1 
The current version is 2.3.0 with 2.3.1 in RC2. 

I will be updating the web sites when Project Sets get approved.